# Using host's tor proxy by docker vm

Tags: docker, proxy, docker-machine, tor

I'm using tor in my host , and my docker **container** should using proxy .
How can I connect host's tor to docker container ?

Note : host's tor are set to using socks protocol in localhost .

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the container with `--net=host` and pass in your proxy env settings, as below:

```
docker run --net=host --env all_proxy=socks://... <IMAGE>
```